# Odoo 12 : How to prevent default field method to be executed

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I scheduled an cron that execute every 1st of the month, the purpose is to allocate leave for all employee according to their tags. here is sample of my code :

```
for leave in leave_type_ids:
    for employee_tag in employee_tag_ids:
        values = {
            'name': 'Allocation mensuelle %s %s' % (now.strftime('%B'), now.strftime('%Y')),
            'holiday_status_id': leave.id,
            'number_of_days': employee_tag.allocation,
            'holiday_type': 'category',
            'category_id': employee_tag.id,
        }
        try:
            self.create(values).action_approve()
        except Exception as e:
            _logger.critical(e)
```

I want to point out that self is instance of 'hr.leave.allocation'.
The problem is when I create the record, the field employee_id is automatically fill with the user/employee OdooBot (the one who executed the program in the cron) and that is not all, the employee OdooBot was allocated a leaves.
This behavior is due to those codes in odoo native modules :

```
    def _default_employee(self):
        return self.env.context.get('default_employee_id') or self.env['hr.employee'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid)], limit=1)
    employee_id = fields.Many2one(
    'hr.employee', string='Employee', index=True, readonly=True,
    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'confirm': [('readonly', False)]}, default=_default_employee, track_visibility='onchange')
```

So my question is how to prevent this when it's the cron and set it to normal when it's in Form view?
The field "employé" should be empty here (in image below), because it is an allocation by tag.
[image: allocation]

Comment: Shouldn't you create allocations for every employee by looping over them?

Comment: @CZoellner odoo did the same by using allocation per tag/category. It is more convinient by tag, if there is an error, we can modify/cancel/... just by one click

Comment: Do you have some example code of Odoo? I don't know that much about HR things in Odoo code :D

Comment: @CZoellner u can check this mehtod "_action_validate_create_childs" in this file addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_leave_allocation.py

Comment: @CZoellner how about setting 'employee_id': False inside values?

Answer (score 0):

You must loop over `hr.employee` because then you can do either of the following:

```
self.with_context({'default_employee_id': employee.id}).create(...)
```

OR

```
self.sudo(employee.id).create(...)
```

Comment: it's difficult to handle allocation by employee so I decided to use tags. Can I set the context 'default_employee_id' to none, for example?

Comment: how about setting 'employee_id': False inside values?